# How to retrive firebase subDocs - flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to retrieve a sub doc from Firebase, I need to collect the number of questions asked and answered by a particular user on their profile page, I am successfully retrieving the no of questions, cuz it's in the main doc,[image 1, main doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZI5q.jpg), but I am not able to retrieve the answers, its a sub doc of questions [image 2 sub doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8h58L.jpg), I tried playing with changing from AsyncSnaphot - DocumentSnapshot - dynamic, but no luck anywhere. Thanking you in advance.

````
```Widget followers(
   BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> asyncSnapshot) {
   return Container(
   color: constantColors.green,
   height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.09,
   child: Row(
    children: [
      Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection('questions')
                  .snapshots(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return Container();
                } else {
                  return Provider.of<Authentication>(context, listen: false)
                              .getUserUid ==
                          asyncSnapshot.data.data()['user uid']
                      ? Text(snapshot.data.docs.length.toString(), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),)
                      : Text('0');
                }
              }),
          Text('asked'),
        ],
      ),
      Column(
        children: [
          StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection('questions').doc().collection('answers')
                  .snapshots(),
              builder: (context, snapshot){
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return Container();
                } else {
                  return Provider.of<Authentication>(context, listen: false)
                      .getUserUid ==
                      asyncSnapshot.data.data()['user uid']
                      ? Text(snapshot.data.docs.length.toString(), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),)
                      : Text('0');
                }
              }),
          Text('answered')

        ],
      )
    ],
  ),
);
````

}     ```

Edit: Adding more code of my answer adding to the firebase feature

```
answerAdder(BuildContext context,
  AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> documentSnapshot, String QuesID) {
  return showModalBottomSheet(
    elevation: 0,
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    isScrollControlled: true,
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.8,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: constantColors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topRight: Radius.circular(25), topLeft: Radius.circular(25)),
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Divider(
              indent: 110,
              endIndent: 110,
              thickness: 4,
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  MaterialButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Provider.of<PostFunctions>(context, listen: false)
                          .addAnswer(
                              context,
                              documentSnapshot.data.data()['question id'],
                              answerController.text,
                              titleController.text)
                          .whenComplete(() {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      });
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                    color: constantColors.cyangrad,
                    child: Text(
                      'add answer',
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                child: TextField(
                  controller: answerController,
                  maxLines: 8,
                  cursorColor: constantColors.green,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                      hintText: 'Please enter your answer',
                      isDense: true,
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                      fillColor: Colors.grey[300],
                      filled: true),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                child: TextField(
                  controller: titleController,
                  maxLines: 8,
                  cursorColor: constantColors.green,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                      hintText: 'Please enter your title',
                      isDense: true,
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                      fillColor: Colors.grey[300],
                      filled: true),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    });}
```

Future method of uploading answer

```
Future addAnswer(BuildContext context, String postId,
  String answer, String answerTitle) async {
  return FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('questions')
    .doc(postId)
    .collection('answers')
    .doc(answerTitle)
    .set({
  'answer': answer,
  'username': Provider.of<FirebaseOps>(context, listen: false).initUsername,
  'user uid':
  Provider.of<Authentication>(context, listen: false).getUserUid,
  'userimage':
  Provider.of<FirebaseOps>(context, listen: false).initUserimage,
  'useremail':
  Provider.of<FirebaseOps>(context, listen: false).initUseremail,
  'time': Timestamp.now(),
});
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in `.collection('questions').doc().collection('answers')`

You need to pass the **doc name** in the `doc()` function. Consider it as a path!

By your example, it should be: 
 `.collection('questions').doc('hoo lala').collection('answers')`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But if you can see my code, I want to check every question programmatically, so I have to go through every document and see If the User has answered any questions, and display the number of answers he answered in their profile.

Comment: For that you need to use a list `.doc(qusetionList[index])`    

And you can populate `questionList` from the 1st one `.collection('questions')` . 

Just use `questionList.add(snapshot.data.docs[index].id)`!
Once the list is populated, trigger the second collection!

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, but I didn't get it, I am very new to programming this is my 1st month of programming, Can you explain me a little deeper?

Comment: Ya sure! I just want to understand your requirement a bit more. Do you just want to show the question and answer count? Or other data as well? And how are you adding the answer? from ur flutter app?

Comment: Please do not put your code in answer, otherwise it will be flagged!
You can edit your question or host your code somewhere and send me a link

Comment: yeah edited, please check, and note, all the three functions are different Change Notifiers and different dart classes

Comment: Maybe you can create one more field inside questions,
"answerCounter" and increase it by one every time an answer is added! But this wont work if simultaneously two different users are adding answers!
Is that the case?

Comment: Another way is to add one `StreamBuilder` [`.collection('questions').doc({question id}).collection('answers').snapshots`] inside another `StreamBuilder` [`.collection('questions').snapshots`]          Nested StreamBuilder!

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answers, Could you help me with one more thing, Is there any way to read all the subdocuments? Or how to retrieve document id, My question is, the answer is a subdocument of the question, I need to go check every question and in every question every subDocument. If there is any way please let me know

Comment: Creating an Answer Counter is not a problem, I want to showcase particular amount of answers, only answered by that particular user